# COUNTIF multiple criteria with different ranges across multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have data on different sheets.

Names of the sheets at a4-a9

```
Sheet1
Sheet2
sheet3
```

In column C contain "name of bank" and in column L contain status (case closed, case open).

Example: I want to count for 'bankA' with status 'case open' across all sheet.

below is the formula I'm using but failed. Please help!

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'"&$A$4:$A$9&"'!C:C"),"bankA",INDIRECT("'"&$A$4:$A$9&"'!L:L"),"Case Open"))
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you isolate what part of the formula is not working by evaluating it? The formula as is worked for me.

Comment: it only count for the sheet1 only. not across the other sheet

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Assuming you have named your list of sheets 'sheets` and your inputs are as stated:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(
 COUNTIFS(
 INDIRECT("'"&sheets&"'!"&"C4:C9"),"BankA",
 INDIRECT("'"&sheets&"'!"&"L4:L9"),"case open"))
```

Comment: it still didnt work. it only calculate the sheet1 only

Comment: It does work and it's correct.  It's proven formula.  Have you checked ranges names and addresses?

Comment: yes, i already checked the range name. Still not working across multiple sheet. i forgot to mention. i'm using this on google sheet. maybe that the reason, its not working?

Comment: @ain I've revised the tags to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(
 INDIRECT(A4&"!C:C"), "BankA",
 INDIRECT(A4&"!L:L"), "case open")+COUNTIFS(
 INDIRECT(A5&"!C:C"), "BankA",
 INDIRECT(A5&"!L:L"), "case open")+COUNTIFS(
 INDIRECT(A6&"!C:C"), "BankA",
 INDIRECT(A6&"!L:L"), "case open"))
```

[image: 0]